# How to get oauth_verifier without manual intervention

Tags: java, oauth, scribe

I am trying to get the access token for LinkedIn
Here's the part of code,

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(LinkedInApi.class).apiKey("My_Api_Key").apiSecret("My_secret_key").build();

System.out.println("LinkedIn Service created");         
Token token = service.getRequestToken();

System.out.println("Got Request token");            
System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(token));
//https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=some_value
Verifier verifier = new Verifier("verifier_you_got_previously");
```

I am able to obtain a request token, and the authorization url which is https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=some_value
To get the Verifier object, I need to pass the verifier value to the constructor. How do I obtain this value? This is a oob request, so there's no callback set to the service.
What should I do with the authorization Url to get the `oauth_verifier`?

Comment: use the inline login if u just want to login.

Comment: you are using scribe, for this just read this post by the author of scribe http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1745

Comment: U check the Javascript API tutorial in developers.linkedin.com
The inline login is the easiest of them all. It gets called in the onload function of the body.. If u still have a doubt I will share u the code...

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi that post is really dated. Sorry, I never updated it :(

Comment: @PabloFernandez:bu you promised in that post :)

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I've been working closely with the LinkedIn guys. There will be a new set of tuts on developer.linkedin.com that will use scribe.

Comment: @PabloFernandez: thats good even myself is using scribe for almost all of my application great work :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server doesn't get the verifier. You need to redirect **your user** to the `authorizationUrl`, then ask them to provide it to you somehow.

This is how OAuth works, you can't trick the system.

Comment: @Pablo, I don't understand how this works. I have successfully load the authorizationURL in a webview, then the user has logged in, and now I get a page with a textbox and the authorization code in it. How do I get the  verifier? Mine does not exist in the URL. I just have the [code]. I am using Scribe.

Comment: @Eenvincible do ypu want to add anything here. got any solution

Comment: Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
                   Verifier verifier = new Verifier(code); then use it inside an AsyncTask - remember this code is obtained inside onResume after the request has resumed.

Answer (score -1):

Use HTTP Client for POST request to authorization URL.

Comment: This wont work since you're not sending the user LinkedIn credentials